# What does the species name 'fistula' mean?

Tags: taxonomy, nomenclature, etymology

*Cassia fistula* is tree with yellow flowers. As a medical student what amazes me is that the word fistula implies other meanings. A fistula, at least in medical science refers to a tract with two epithelial openings.

Comment: Have you looked at pictures of the plant, especially the fruit? Fistula is the latin word for tube. It is used in medicine, but also in botany. So basically, the word fistula does not only imply other meanings, it has other meanings.

Comment: @skymningen could you post it as an answer? Yes now I recall. It has long tube shaped pods. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The botanic and medical term *fistula* is directly derived from the latin word *[fistula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fistula#Etymology)* meaning tube or pipe.

Both the medical fistula and the fruits of the *Cassia fistula* tree show phenotypes similar to a tube.

I will spare everyone the medical example picture, but here are the [fruit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6hren-Kassie#/media/File:Manna_im_Verkauf_fcm.jpg) of *Cassia fistula*, which are sold as "manna":

[image: You can even eat it!]